# Do legendary skins count as unowned in trades?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have found [this article](https://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2018-09-06-pokemon-go-trading-requirements-special-trades-how-to-trade-5392) about the cost for trades. It states that:

> Standard Pokémon Trades:
>
> - Regional exclusives
> - Forms you don't have in your Pokédex (think Unown, Alolan and Castform)
> - Any other Pokémon not in your Pokédex that isn't Legendary or Shiny
>
> Special Trades:
>
> - Legendary Pokémon
> - Shiny Pokémon

And for the trade costs (depending on the friend level

```
Standard Pokémon                100         80          8       4
Shiny or Legendary (Owned)      20,000      16,000      1,600   800
Shiny or Legendary (Unowned)    1,000,000   800,000     80,000  40,000
```

Here is my situation:

I only have the Armoured Mewtwo, not the regular one. If I trade with someone for a normal Mewtwo, is it an owned legendary trade or an unwoned legendary trade?

I only know, that regular Pokemons that are shiny or with skin (Pikachu with hats) count as an owned Special Trade, if you only have the regular one.

Comment: The referred article you linked from eurogamer, while generally correct on the trading mechanism, has several inaccuracies.

Comment: If there are inaccuracies regarding to my question, it would be nice if you could comment them.

Comment: I was referring to the article, and the inaccuracies are too many to enumerate.  But pertaining to what you quoted, for example, stardust cost for regular pokemon is 100 at every friend level.  Overall, these are relatively minor details with respect to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/caxrc4/armored_mewtwo_and_trade/) thread, the following will occur while trading

- Trading an Armored Mewtwo for normal Mewtwo without owning a normal Mewtwo will count as an owned special trade
- Trading a Normal Mewtwo for Armored Mewtwo without owning a Armored Mewtwo will count as an unowned special trade.

Each Pokémon that have variants, such as costumed, forms, or alolans, has a base and non-base forms. Base is considered the original version, such as normal Mewtwo. Non-Base would be any variants, such as Armored Mewtwo. If you have the base form, but not the variant, the variant will be considered unowned. If you have the variant, but not the base, then the base will be considered owned.

To test this, I used two accounts - Account A had both forms of Exeggutor and Account B only had alolan Exeggutor.<sup>1</sup> In the confirmation screen for accepting the trade for regular Exeggutor and alolan Exeggutor, the trade was considered an owned and did not count as a special trade despite Account B not owning a regular Exeggutor

---

<sup>1</sup> No Pokémon were harmed during this experiment